# creating sets of tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

How do i create a set of tuples with each tuple containing two elements? Each tuple will have an `x` and `y` value: `(x,y)`
I have the numbers 1 through 50, and want to assign `x` to all values 1 through 50 and `y` also 1 through 50.

```
S = {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)...(1,50),(2,1)......(50,50)}
```

I tried

```
positive = set(tuple(x,y) for x in range(1,51) for y in range(1,51))
```

but the error message says that a tuple only takes in one parameter. What do I need to do to set up a list of tuples?

Comment: change `tuple(x,y)` to `(x,y)`

Comment: ..because `tuple` converts other iterables into tuples (e.g. `tuple([1,2])` -> `(1,2)`), so it expects only one argument.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
mySet = set(itertools.product(range(1,51), repeat=2))
```

OR

```
mySet = set((x,y) for x in range(1,51) for y in range(1,51))
```

Answer (score 6):

`tuple` accepts only one argument. Just explicitly write in the tuple instead using parentheses.

```
#                  vvvvv
>>> positive = set((x,y) for x in range(1,5) for y in range(1,5))
>>> positive
{(1, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (4, 1), (3, 1), (4, 4), (2, 1), (2, 4), (2, 3), (1, 4), (4, 3), (2, 2), (4, 2), (3, 4), (1, 1)}
```