# python - dictionary with set of tuples as value is not created correctly

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344938/creating-sets-of-tuples-in-python) but it does not seem to work for me -

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict[ "a" ] = set(("1111","test1"))
>>> dict
{'a': set(['1111', 'test1'])}
>>> dict[ "a" ].add( ("2222","test2"))
>>> dict
{'a': set(['1111', 'test1', ('2222', 'test2')])}
```

I was expecting also the first one to look like a tuple - why is that splitted?

I want when doing :

```
>>> for key,val_set in dict.items() :
...     for val in val_set :
...             print val
...
1111
test1
('2222', 'test2')
```

to have 2 items printed not three.

Comment: The tuple is converted to a set. Wrap a list around it: `set([("1111","test1")])`

Comment: Did you mean `set([("1111","test1")])` perhaps?

Comment: You have got your answer but I will advice you to use defaultdict(set). It's easy and real approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set()` takes the values from *an iterable* and adds each value separately. You passed in a tuple, which is an iterable with two values.

If you wanted to add the *tuple itself*, you need to wrap that in an iterable, like a list:

```
set([("1111","test1")])
```

In Python 3, you can instead use a set display to create a new set:

```
{("1111","test1")}
```

A set display takes elements separated by commas, and `("1111", "test1")` is one tuple element here.

In the other post, the set was created with a set display (so `{tuple1, tuple2, etc.}`) and the answers used either an `itertools` function or a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to produce the sequence of tuples for the `set()` function to process; a  both produce an iterable type.

Answer (score 2):

You have got your answer but I will advice you to use defaultdict instead. All these type of cases like this set([("1111","test1")]) are properly handled. You don't have to worry about initialize too.

Try This.

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = defaultdict(set)
s["a"].add(("pw", "sq"));
s["a"].add(("wq", "qq"));
s["a"].add(("aa", "bb"));

for k, v in s.items():
   print (k)
   for g in v:
       print (g)
```

And please note this, I have assumed all your values opposite your keys are sets.
if this is not the case, go with the first one.